# Is there any advantage of of using comma over + to concatenate primitive types in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have seen commas to concatenate primitive data types in Javascript and was wondering whether there was any difference in using a comma over say the `+` operator as well as the .concat() function?

So an example the following statement gives me abc

```
var value1 = a, value2 = b, value3 = c;
document.write(value1,value2,value3);
```

Comment: Whether this works depends on the function.... `var a = 'a', 'b', 'c';` would do something different than you expect.

Comment: @Felix Kling - I did not realize that `var a = 'a', 'b', 'c'` was valid.

Comment: @FelixKling he is talking about the document.write() vs contatenating.

Comment: @Felix Kling - Unless I misunderstood, I get the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected string` when declaring a variable as `var a = 'a', 'b', 'c';`

Comment: Well, then skip the `var`. In that case, `a` would be assigned the value `'c'`. Commas don't concatenate values. When calling functions, they delimit arguments and anywhere else they just separate expressions. It seems that `document.write` is set up to expect an unlimited number of parameters, but that does not have to hold for  all functions. So your question about advantages can actually not be asked, since you cannot compare string concatenation to argument passing. Or am I missing the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since string concatenation is one of the haviest operations on computing, using `document.write` with various parameters would perform better.

See this test (it sometimes hangs in IE, so use other browser please) http://jsperf.com/document-write-vs-concatenation

Explaination:

```
document.write("val1", "val2", "val3");
```

is equivalent to

```
document.write("val1");
document.write("val2");
document.write("val3");
```

Thus, being much faster, since it doesn't concatenates the strings.

Answer (score 3):

Apples and oranges. Nothing is being concatenated in your example; you are simply specifying 3 arguments to the `write()` function.

`document.write(exp1, exp2, exp3, ...)` accepts multiple parameters, and when given multiple parameters it will iterate through them all as if you called `write()` on each one individually.

However, the comma does have a use when evaluating expressions where it is used to process multiple expressions and returns the last one. To see that in action you need to wrap your parameters in a set of parenthesis so that it forms a single parameter:

```
document.write("a","b","c") // abc
document.write( ("a", "b", "c") )  // c 

alert("a","b","c") // a
alert( ("a","b","c") ) // c
alert( (x=2, ++x) ) // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

In most browsers (IE <= 8, Gecko) string concatenation using the + operator has horrible performance.

In my company, for example, we have to compose a large HTML fragment piece by piece. In this case we have something like this:

```
var id = 123;
var html = [];
html.push('<div id="', id, '">hello</div>');
var result = html.join('');
```

In the case where you have LOTS of concatenations, this is MUCH better than the following:

```
var id = 123;
result = '<div id="' + id + '">hello</div>';
```

So to answer your question - it really depends on the situation. If you are concatenating many strings together you should never use the + operator due to poor performance. But it should be fine 99% of the time where the performance gain will be so little it is just painful to try anything else. But in cases where you actually have the option to comma separate (like in the case of array.push, or document.write) then you should definately take advantage of it.

Comment: The `+` operator isn't particularly "horrible" in older IE. I think you're confusing it with the compound `+=` operator, which was slow.

Comment: Incidentally, in IE 8, using push/join is much slower than concatenation (both + and +=). So if you plan is to help IE performance, avoid *push* and assign to an index property.